# Why's the Build and Analyze command not finding obvious memory management errors?

Tags: iphone, xcode, clang, clang-static-analyzer

For some reason, the Clang Static Analyzer in my Xcode doesn't complain about anything. I made big memory management mistakes to try it (alloc and no release), but it never finds them and doesn't complain about them. Even after clean all targets and again Build and Analyze.

I was building for Simulator 3.1

Must I set that up specifically? A special compiler setting or so? How?

Comment: You'll probably have to tell us in more detail about what your code says, what you do in Xcode (step by step), and what output you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang isn't perfect.

Edit: But that isn't necessarily the case in this senario.

Comment: Sure it isn't, but it never finds anything, no matter where and how many memory management errors I make for testing purpose of clang ;) ...something is definitely wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you compile with Clang and not with gcc ?

Comment: Did you do a "Clean" prior to using the Clang Static Analyzer?